# $P(P(x)-2)=4P(x)+3 \Rightarrow P(-1)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the value $P(-1)$ for the polynomial $P(x)$
with real coefficents satisfying $P(P(x)-2)=4P(x)+3$.

My answer is: Since $\deg (P \circ Q)=\deg P \cdot \deg Q$ for two non-constant polynomials $P,Q$, $P(x)$ has to be linear. 
Let $P(x)=ax+b$, after calculations we get $P(x)=4x+11$ and then $P(-1)=7$.

I wonder that what can be the alternative solutions of this question?

Comment: Polynomials can have any degree. Can you justify the fact that you have taken only linear polynomials? (I know the answer, but I'd like to know if you know it too. Then your answer would be complete)

Comment: @b00nheT I think he knows that. But if OP doesn't include that in his answer, his answer is incomplete (it just assumes that $P$ is a linear polynomial)

Comment: I perfectly agree about the second part. About the first: I can't know about that, but I'll delete my comment anyway because I find it too exhaustive.

Comment: Suppose you knew that for some value $x_0$ we had $P(x_0)-2 = -1$, i.e. $P(x_0) = 1$. Then we would have $P(-1) = P(P(x_0)-2) = 4P(x_0)+3 = 7$. But showing that there has to exist $x_0$ such that $P(x_0)=1$ might be more difficult without directly proving that $P$ has to be linear.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i made a edit to the question. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user315531 I think the answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any polynomial $P(x)$ such that 
$$P(P(x)-2) = 4P(x)+3\tag{*1}$$
There are two possibilities.

1. $P(x) = c$ is a constant polynomial, then $(*1)$ reduces to 
   $$c = 4 c + 3\quad\implies\quad c = -1 \quad\implies\quad P(-1) = -1$$
2. If $P(x)$ is not a constant polynomial, then $P(\mathbb{R})$, then image of $\mathbb{R}$ under $t \mapsto P(t)$ consists of infinitely many points. This means for infinitely many $u \in \mathbb{R}$, we can find a $v \in \mathbb{R}$ to rewrite $u$ as $P(v) - 2$. For such $u$, we have
   $$P(u) = P(P(v) - 2) = 4P(v)+3 = 4(u+2)+3 = 4u+11$$
   Since the two polynomials $P(x)$ and $4x + 11$ agree on infinitely many points, they agree on all points. This leads to
   $$P(-1) = 4(-1) + 11 = 7$$

Combine these, we conclude $P(-1)$ can take two and only two possible values, namely $-1$ and $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=ax^n+o(x^n)$ with $n\geq 1$ and $a\not=0$. Then 
$$P(P(x)-2)-4P(x)-3=P(ax^n+o(x^n))-4ax^n+o(x^n)=a^2x^{n^2}+o(x^{n^2})-4ax^n+o(x^n).$$
If this polynomial is identically zero then $n^2=n$ and $a^2=4a$ that is $n=1$ and $a=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{P}\pars{\mrm{P}\pars{x} -2} & = 4\,\mrm{P}\pars{x} + 3 \implies
\mrm{P}\pars{\mrm{P}\pars{x} -2} = 4\bracks{\mrm{P}\pars{x} - 2} + 11
\\[5mm]
\implies \mrm{P}\pars{-1} & = 4\pars{-1} + 11 = \bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{7}
\end{align}